# Testing In Golang, how to test cache that expires in 30 seconds

Tags: go, testing, caching, testify

I have an interface called localcache:

```golang
package localcache

type Cache interface {
    Set(k string, v interface{})  error
    Get(k string) (interface{}, error)
}
```

and another file containing its implementation

```golang
type cache struct {
    pool map[string]value
}

type value struct {
    data      interface{}
    expiredAt time.Time
}

func New() *cache {
    if cacheInstance == nil {
        once.Do(func() {
            cacheInstance = &cache{
                pool: make(map[string]value),
            }
            go cacheInstance.spawnCacheChcker()
        })
        return cacheInstance
    }
    return cacheInstance
}

func (c *cache) Set(k string, v interface{}) (e error) {
    expiredAt := time.Now().Add(expiredIn)
    c.pool[k] = value{data: v, expiredAt: expiredAt}
    e = nil
    return
}

func (c *cache) Get(k string) (v interface{}, e error) {
    v = c.pool[k].data
    e = nil
    return
}

func (c *cache) spawnCacheChcker() {
    for {
        for k, v := range c.pool {
            if !(v.expiredAt.Before(time.Now())) {
                continue
            }
            c.evictCache(k)
        }
        time.Sleep(checkInBetween)
    }
}
```

a cache will be expired 30 seconds after it's been set, how can I test this functionality?
I'm using testify rn, my brute force solution was to time.Sleep in the test function, but I feel like this will prolong the entire test process, which is not the best practice.

Is there any ways to mock the `expiredAt` inside the Set function? Or is there any workaround that tests this better?

Comment: If you want to check keys to evict in a goroutine via spawnCacheChcker will be better use a mutex (rwlock maybe) when read / write / delete.

Comment: Another approach is to only evict the key when you access it. Check if expired and delete if need. If you really need to use a goroutine, use a time Ticker instead Sleep and consider receive context.Context to avoid goroutine leaking (by cancel when it is not needed)

Answer (score 3):

You can move `time.Now()` to be a field in cache struct like

```
type cache struct {
  nowFunc func() time.Time
}
```

then assign time.Now to it in the constructor. Within the test, just modify it to your mock function to return any time you want.